# Get two strings in a single column from a table SQL Query

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table `People`:

```
Name     LastName     Address
-----------------------------------------------------------
John     Doe          99 Street. Random Address 101
John     Doe2         98 Street. Random number Address 101
```

If want to search in the `Address` column something like '98 Random number' - then `john doe2` row should be returned.

I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM People 
WHERE Address LIKE %98 Random number%
```

but it returns nothing.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Which RDBMS it is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Address LIKE '%98%Random number%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Address LIKE '%98%' AND Address LIKE '%Random number%'
```